# Issue in using async/await function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to this whole async function concept. Here is the function that I want to use:

```
async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const resultRes = await fetch("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters?category=Better+Call+Saul");
      const result = await resultRes.json();
      
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
```

And this is what function call looks like:

```
const Data = fetchData();
```

Now I want to console.log(Data) with the array that is returned but intead it shows as a promise object.
How should I use this function as using it with .then messes up my whole app as the containing file is a react component?

Comment: an async function, by its definition, returns a Promise ... try `fetchData().then(Data => console.log(Data))` ... or `const Data = await fetchData()` if you can - i.e. top level of a module or inside an `async function`

Comment: try in this way `const Data = await  fetchData();`

Comment: but the containing function is not async and making it async makes that function return a promise which doesn't seem to work in reactDOM.render()

Comment: Well, then it's time to `useState` and `useEffect` ... However before that I'd recommend to get familiar with asynchrony in JS.

Comment: asynchrony is like a virus - it infects everything it touches, and there is no cure. if you think of asynchrony as giving you a result at some undetermined time in the future, you'll soon understand that it can't be "predicted" - unless code can time travel - which it can't

Comment: I do understand in theory how asynchrony is working but when trying to work with it in actual code is proving very hard